# Why there are more than 1 hello message from client to server while opening secure channel in OPC UA?

Tags: java, milo

[HEL_MSG_3_Times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K5tj.png)I have capture the wire-shark packet while OPC UA Server and Client communication on going. In the packet there are more than 1 hello message from client to server for establishing the secure channel.

Do anyone have idea why there are more than 1 hello message.
I have attached image for references.

Answer (score 0):

What your capture shows is 2 connections that were used to call the GetEndpoints service and a 3rd that was presumably used to connect to one of the Endpoints chosen from the previous GetEndpointsResponse.

I don't know why you're seeing 2 separate connections and GetEndpoints calls - probably depends on the application you're using.